# Limitation storage of azure search is 2.4 TB?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

[image: Information limit]

As shown in the  picture, I find a limit about storage of Azure search.
I have a data with total size up to 500 Terabyte. 
I want create 4 Container and  4 Azure search index using data from 4 container.
So, I can create Azure Search Index with Storage more 2.4TB? Or what is solutions for our problem?

Comment: That's a question for Azure's site and support, not StackOverflow. You may need more services (it says 2.4TB *per service*) or a custom solution

Comment: I want confirm about limit 2.4 TB documents of Azure Search.

Comment: Besides, are you going to upload 500TB of data *right after you go into production*? Or is 500TB the expected maximum load? Why not start with what you *really* need and scale it as appropriate?

Comment: @HùngLê you are asking the wrong questions then. So what if you can upload 500TB? What about the *CPU and RAM* required to search it? You'll either have to buy that much Compute capacity as well, or start small and scale as you need it

Comment: @HùngLê in any case, if you want to *confirm*, contat Microsoft, not StackOverflow.

Comment: This overview of my project. I have 500TB data and i want using it. I want confirm is azure search working with 500TB data.

Comment: @HùngLê Azure Search is limited to 2.4 TB per search service. We would be interested to learn more about your scenario and how you're measuring the size of the data you want to index. Please email me at bruce.johnston at microsoft dot com.